# How to host and publish Alfresco WCM

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm very new to Alfresco and trying to get hold of it. I'm using Community edition 4.2 and I've created one website using Alfresco Share and I did not imported Government/Finance website data. Below is the screenshot - 
[image]

Now I've created two folders under Document Library tab and have uploaded few PDFs into that. It looks like below -

[image]

Now if I click on publish link then its saying that "There is no appropriate channel for this content". 
I entered ubswcm as URL name while creating this site.

I followed the link http://docs.huihoo.com/alfresco/Getting-Started-with-WCM-for-Alfresco-Commumity-Edition-3.2.pdf which talks about stating but I could not find staging in this version of Alfresco 4.2.

My questions

1. How can I publish this content?
2. How can I run this website on localhost? Do I need to create war file? If so then please advice how to proceed on this.
3. http://:8080/wcmqs running fine. How can I build slimier site like this in http://:8080/ubswcm ? Please suggest if you have any tutorial on this.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow a tutorial on the Alfresco *Web Quick Start* capabilities. You should find that these capabilities are well-documented on [docs.alfresco.com](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/index.jsp), e.g. [Using Alfresco Web Quick Start](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/qs-intro.html).

Do not confuse Web Quick Start with the *Social Publishing* framework (which the *Publish* action is associated with) or with the legacy AVM-based WCM services (which I assume the PDF refers to, but I could not tell for sure as you link gives me a 404) that are no longer supported in Alfresco 4.

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for this clarification. Please correct me, if understanding is wrong - earlier version of Alfresco, AVM was used but now it has been removed.  In Alfresco 4, I need to use Alfresco Share to build a website. If so, then how can I import Website data (Like Govt. or Finance website which comes with Web Quick Start) or create my new website data? I've created two folders under Document Library  and created content under this but when I tried to preview this as Web Asset then I'm getting message like "Unable to Preview Web Asset". Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: You need to add the _Web Quick Start_ dashlet to your site dashboard in order to perform the import.

Comment: Hi Will, if I add this to dashlet and then Web Quick start import gives 2 options to import either Government or Finance data but I do not want to use those two options. I want to import my own custom site like Health Care. How can I do it? My second question - I've created two folders under Document Library and created content under this but when I tried to preview this as Web Asset then I'm getting message like "Unable to Preview Web Asset". Please let me know if I'm missing something here. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: I would not recommend that you create the folder structures manually. They are complex and must be in the right format. It is better that you import an existing set of data and then customize the content from there.

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to know how is it possible to do that. Please share your knowledge on this. And do you have any idea about the bug https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-14587       I don't find resolution of this.

Comment: It is indeed possible to build your own web site structure, this is infact what I did for propedeutic purpose. But as Will advice, there are a few properties and aspects you have to add later. Best advice I could give you, create a brand new site, import the finance wcmqs from there. Then compare with and apply the same aspects and properties to your proper site.